# Peewee : How to validate login details on form submit

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

Currently I am working on the project . I am new python , peewee.

I need to check given login credentials valid or not ?

I searched so many sites to find this ans. But i am getting exact ans what i want ?

Find something i done below :

```
def process(self):
    email = self.get_argument("username")
    password = self.get_argument("password")
    print Email, Password
    try:
        result = Employee.select().where(Employee.Email_ID == email , Employee.Password == password)
        print 'Query is ', result
        if result == None:
            print 'Failure'
        else:
            print 'Success'
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return self.render_template("index.py")
```

can you help me out in this. I did wrong? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you check result for None in Python try to compare with "is".

```
if result is None:
    .....
```

It is more efficient to just check "reference" to None.

I think you error is in you  **where**  method.

```
.where(Employee.Email_ID == email , Employee.Password == password)
```

Maybe,

```
.where(Employee.Email_ID = email , Employee.Password = password)
```

Comment: I tried '.where(Employee.Email_ID = email , Employee.Password = password)' . But still no luck . It shows an error like statement expected.

Comment: what about .get()! .where(Employee.Email_ID == email , Employee.Password == password).get()

Comment: When try to using get! .. it shows an error like `Instance matching query does not exist:`